# How does spy tools like ali hunter and ppspy get data from shopify stores

Tags: api

How does spy tools like Ali-hunter and ppspy get data from Shopify stores, normally in order to get this data you'll need to use a webhook, but this only applies to your store and stores that installed your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PPSPY does the following.

- It reads your Shopify sitemap to find the products in the store.
  .../sitemap_products_1.xml
- As fallback, it parses the URL:
  .../collections/all?sort_by=best-selling - and tries
  to find the products there.
- Next, it uses the JSON URL from Shopify. There again it tries to find
  all products. An example URL:
  .../products.json?page=1&limit=250 - most store owners don't even know this exists.
- After that, it calls the JSON URL for each product. You can get this
  URL in your online store by simply opening a product page and writing
  ".json" after it in the URL. Example URL:
  .../products/your-productname.json.

In this JSON there is a field "updated_at". This field is updated every time a change is made. Also, when an order take place (the stock is changed).

And with this, it is possible to track the sales (approximately).

Comment: Looks like Shopify made a change where the “updated_at” field updates seemingly at randomly. Any ideas now?

Comment: @DS-King how do they check the product.json for changes though? Is there a webhook available? If not, wouldn't using a cron job to check it every few seconds be too resource intensive? Or did it show the inventory levels in the past and so you calculate the difference every day?

Comment: @EricSmith I'm also trying to understand this. Would you want to connect privately to discuss what we know?

Answer (score 0):

They are called web scraper or crawlers. They go to your product page (going through all the links in your ecommerce) and understand the content of the page. They extract the product name and the product price. They will do that every X hours or X days and collect the information, so they don't need any webhook.

In theory you could make your page complicated enough to not make it easy to crawl, for example you could show the price with Javascript (the crawlers typically have javascript not enabled). But that would make your website less accessible, especially to Google, which is in fact another crawler.

Comment: thanks, but they could only scrape the title, images, description, price, etc... scraping only won't be enough for them to get the live sales a store gets